# Any simple way of using forms authentification based on user roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I want to make a application for customers.
It should contain :

- 1.Login page
- 2.Page for simple users
- 3.Page for administrators

I've found on google a lot of examples but 90% of examples have 20+ pages with some a lot of advanced things and I can't handle reading everything from them.

I just want to make a simple login page , and use 'user role' for the page where user is redirected and 'administrator role' for the page where administrator is redirected.

When I'll finish the page I will public it on a webhosting , and the main problem is that I need user roles,pass,name in a database in asp not on a website .

Is there any easy example to follow ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a long time I had the same problem - most examples have you create the default schema which has a crazy number of tables.

The simplest example I have found is:

[How to: Implement Simple Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx)

It doesn't deal with the persistence layer at all, so it is really simple to adapt as you see fit.

Comment: Okay thanks but , what if I want to deny a folder with some web files to be accessed by normal users ? shall I create a column with id,username,password,status , where the status is "User or Admin" and on the login page I get the status of the user and if he's administrator I will redirect him to the admin page with a cookie containing his status , and on the admin page I will request the cookie containing the status , if is not admin then I will redirect him to login page , is this a good idea?if yes , it's safe from protecting the pages?

Comment: @jax please ask that as a new question